# On one of my sites a file is shown as 404 but the file IS there

Tags: javascript, wordpress, long-polling

I am building a WordPress plugin. The plugin works beautifully on one site.

But on every other site I've tried so far one of the resource files used it getting a 404 (Not Found) error in the console. If I post the url, displayed in the console as not found, in the address bar the file is accessible.

The site it works on is not in a root directory, while one it doesn't work on is on the same server, in the root directory and is a multisite installation. I've tried it on other servers, and sometimes it works, on others it doesn't'. I'm baffled by what might cause this... Any feedback would be appreciated.

The following code is posted using a action into the header of a page:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">
    (function($){
            $(document).ready(function(){               
                lpStart();
            });
            var lpOnComplete = function(response) {

                // do more processing
                lpStart();
            };

            function lpStart() {
                $.post("'.plugin_dir_url(__FILE__).'filename", {varname: "'.$value.'"}, lpOnComplete, "json");
            };
        })(jQuery);
</script>';
```

The URL that is said to not exist is the one that is posted to in function lpStart().

Interestingly, when it doesn't work I get the following error in the console as the page loads.

```
GET http://example.com/undefined 404 (Not Found)
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the value of __FILE__ is not that which you expect, as an example run the line "echo __FILE__;" [here](http://writecodeonline.com/php/), you'll notice that the result is not www.site.com/homepage/... but rather /homepage/... This might not be the problem but it's where to start.

Second port of call, hopefully where the problem lies, is where the GET file is located. Say we have a file system structure of

home

```
ajaxStuff/
  example.php
main/
 index.php
```

and our site entry point is /main/

in order to call the ajaxStuff example the relative url must tell the server to step up a branch in the directory before trying to enter ajaxStuff and indeed run example.php by writing something like

```
url: "../ajaxStuff/example.php"
```

And if all else fails - are you porting over from a server which doesn't use a case sensitive file system (windows) to one that does, if so check the string case for each file.

Comment: Interesting. I'm pretty sure the file IS where I say it is because if I visit the url that the console tells me is not there, I get to the page I want. The network tab even has the ajax response I want... Thanks for your input.

I'm currently using a full URL to long poll the file. Would a relative url work better with an ajax call verses a full url?

Comment: In most cases it's probably fair to say that a relative url system is the better choice since static ones don't accommodate for url changes or directory structure changes.

Does the source equivalent of \__FILE__ start with 'http://'? I'm not entirely convinced it will make a difference (get method dependent) but I'm sure the protocol has to be declared, in this case the http.

Comment: Hmm, relative url didn't work. I think I may try re-writing the plugin from scratch. Maybe I'll stumble on the solution.